# Building a minimal linux kernel for vmware

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am building a linux kernel for a vmware machine for learning kernel development (understanding and using basic kernel APIs for writing kernel code). What configuration options can i safely turn off, if i want a minimal kernel?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: try `make kvmconfig`